# Can I use component Box inside Grid component in MUI? Is it correct practice?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The above code is only a example. My original code it's working perfectly, but I would like write better.

**Example of code:**

```
<Grid container justifyContent="space-between">
  <Box display = "flex">
     <Typography> Hello World</Typography>
  </Box>
 <OthersComponents/>
 ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Grid container that has children Grid items.

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item>
     <Typography>Item 1</Typography>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
     <Typography>Item 2</Typography>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Check out the docs for other props: https://mui.com/api/grid/